# golang send a lambda capturing group

Tags: go, lambda

I use a lot of c++ and when using it I often use lambdas. Lambdas have

```
[<capturing group>](<parameters>) -> <return type> {}.
```

in golang I know that lambdas are just

```
var lambda_exp = func(<parameter list>) <return type> {}
```

but how can i replicate the capturing group?

Comment: Variables in Go are automatically captured when used, there is no need to declare which to capture. See [the spec on function literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has a whole bunch of fiddly stuff to control:

- which variables are captured
- what their lifetime might be
- whether they're captured by value or by reference

and so on.  These come with a huge number of complicated rules you as a programmer must obey; if you don't, your code behavior is undefined.  The result is wonderfully unclear code that only a master C++ programmer can maintain, and job security for life.<sup>1</sup>

Go lacks all of this complexity.  A programmer is forced to write clear and simple code: code that will not baffle the reader.  The lifetime of a variable is figured out automatically by the compiler and runtime.

Well, lucky for us programmers, there *is* one bit of complexity.  A loop of the form:

```golang
for i, item := range someslice {
    go func() {
        operateOn(i, &item)
    }()
}
```

has only one single (shared) variable named `item`, so that each of the spawned goroutines is working on the *same* item, whose value is overwritten on each trip through the loop.  This means you must write the somewhat less clear:

```golang
for i, item := range someslice {
    item := item
    go func() {
        operateOn(i, &item)
    }()
}
```

(note that `i` is not a problem because its value is just its value, not a pointer; I use this again below) or:

```golang
for i, item := range someslice {
    go func(x T) {
        operateOn(i, &x)
    }(item)
}
```

to properly capture the item in a local variable within the closure.

---

<sup>1</sup>In case it wasn't obvious, I'm actually happy that the Go code is so simple and clear.  I'm being at least a little sarcastic about the job-security-for-life aspect of C++ programming.  The fiddly stuff *does* allow C++ to be memory efficient and not require a runtime GC, in many cases, but it's just a nightmare.  This is, e.g., why Rust's ownership model stuff exists, but Rust takes some getting used to.